# $ \mathbb{R}P^n $ bundles over the circle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles, mapping-class-groups

Is every $ \mathbb{R}P^{2n} $ bundle over the circle trivial?

Are there exactly two $ \mathbb{R}P^{2n+1} $ bundles over the circle?

This is a cross-post of (part of) my MSE question

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349052/diffeomorphisms-of-spheres-and-real-projective-spaces

which has been up for a couple weeks and got 8 upvotes and some nice comments but no answers.

My intuition for thinking both answer are yes is that there are exactly 2 sphere bundles over the circle. The trivial one and then the non-trivial (and non-orientable) one which can be realized as the mapping torus of an orientation reversing map of the sphere. So importing that intuition to projective spaces then the orientable $ \mathbb{R}P^{2n+1} $ should have a nontrivial (and non orientable) bundle over the circle while the non orientable $ \mathbb{R}P^{2n} $ should have only the trivial bundle. For $ n=1 $ this checks out since that projective space is orientable and thus we have exactly two bundles over the circle (the trivial one=the 2 torus and the nontrivial one=the Klein bottle).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer is correct if appropriately understood, but it's a little subtle. Here I should note that I'm interpreting your question as a purely homotopy theoretic one (in particular ignoring smooth structure), and that by "bundle" you mean "Serre bundle". If you care about smooth bundles, see Tom Goodwillie's answer.

The way I know to do this involves a little algebraic topology.

First, it's always the case that $X$-bundles over a circle (for $X$ some topological space) are classified by the group $\pi_0(\mathrm{Aut}(X)),$ where $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is the group of maps $X\to X$ which are invertible up to homotopy. Thus a good technique to carry out this classification is to first find all self-maps $X\to X$ up to homotopy, then see which ones are invertible.

Now we want to specialize to the case $X = RP^n,$ for some $n$. However it turns out that it's much easier to classify maps not into $RP^n$ itself, but rather into $RP^\infty.$ Namely, maps from some space $X$ to $RP^\infty$ up to homotopy are always classified by $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}/2)$ (equivalently, this is group homomorphisms from $\pi_1(X)$ into $\mathbb{Z}/2$). Now the difference between $RP^n$ and $RP^\infty$ isn't actually too terrible. Namely, the CW approximation theorem tells us that any map $RP^n\to RP^\infty$ actually can be chosen up to homotopy such that it factorizes through $RP^n\subset RP^\infty.$ So we can compute
$$\pi_0\mathrm{Maps}(RP^n, RP^\infty) \cong H^1(RP^n, \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2.$$
The element $0\in \mathbb{Z}/2$ corresponds to the trivial map $$*:RP^n\to RP^n$$ mapping everything to a basepoint in $RP^\infty$ and the nontrivial element  $1\in \mathbb{Z}/2$ corresponds to the identity map, $$id:RP^n\to RP^n\subset RP^\infty.$$ And any other map $RP^n\to RP^n$ will be homotopy equivalent to one of these as an element of $\mathrm{Maps}(RP^n, RP^\infty)$.
However there's a catch: while any map $RP^n\to RP^n$ is homotopy equivalent to one of the maps $id, *$ *as a map to $RP^\infty$,* the homotopy between the two maps might not live in $RP^n$. So a priori, there can be multiple homotopy classes of self-maps of $RP^n$ homotopic to one of these maps in $RP^\infty$ (and indeed, sometimes there are). To get a handle on how badly maps to $RP^\infty$ are undercounting, you can apply the CW approximation theorem again to see that any homotopy between two maps $RP^n\to RP^\infty$ will factorize, up to homotopy, through $$RP^{n+1}\subset RP^\infty.$$ The "error" of such a homotopy existing in $RP^n$ will be classified by a map to the quotient, $$RP^n\times [0,1]\to RP^{n+1}/RP^n\cong S^{n+1},$$ taking both $RP^n\times \{0\}, RP^n\times \{1\}$ to the basepoint, in other words, a based map from the space $$RP^n_+\wedge S^1 = \Sigma(RP^n_+)$$ (you can think of this as the ordinary suspension $\Sigma(RP^n)$ with the two suspension points identified) to $S^{n+1}.$ Let's write $$D: = \pi_0\text{Maps}(RP^n_+\wedge S^1, S^n)$$ for the set of possible such "defects" of a homotopy in $RP^{n+1}$ restricting to $RP^n$.

Based maps from a closed $n+1$-dimensional manifold to $S^{n+1}$ are classified by ordinary $H^{n+1},$ and so we have $$D \cong H^{n+1}(\Sigma(RP^n_+)) \cong H^n(RP^n) \cong \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}/2, & n\text{ even}\\
\mathbb{Z}, & n\text{ odd}.
\end{cases}$$

Thus for each of the maps $*, id: RP^n\to RP^n,$ there can be at worst $D$ worth of distinct other homotopy classes of self-maps $RP^n\to RP^n$ homotopic to it as maps to $CP^{\infty}.$ Since a map homotopic to $*$ cannot be an automorphism (it would have to induce the trivial map on $H^1$ which cannot come from an automorphism), we can restrict our attention to maps homotopic in $CP^\infty$ to $id:RP^n\to RP^n.$ A priori, there could have been elements of $D$ which are not realizable as "defects" of homotopies between maps $RP^n\to RP^n$, but in this case we don't run into this problem: indeed, every element of $D$ occurs as the defect of some homotopy $RP^n\times [0,1]\to RP^{n+1}$ between the identity $id:RP^n\to RP^n$ and another map. Namely, recall that we have realized $D \cong H^n(RP^n)$ as a cyclic group, either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2$ (depending on parity). Let $\alpha$ be a generator of this group. Then every element of $D$ can be written $k\alpha$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. By doing a calculation, you can see that each element $k\alpha\in D$ is realized as the defect of the homotopy $$[0,1]\cdot RP^n\to RP^{n+1}$$ induced by the map $[0,1]\times S^n\to S^{n+1}$ given by rotating $S^n$ in a circle around some ($n-1$-dimensional) axis inside $S^{n+1},$ by an angle of $$k\cdot \pi.$$ Now if $n$ is even, we see the resulting "new" map $RP^n\to RP^n$ is once again the identity. If $n$ is odd, the new map is induced from the "reflection" map given by
$$\sigma:(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)\mapsto (-x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)$$
(in some coordinates). Thus from what we've done so far, there can be at most two homotopy invertible self-maps up to homotopy $$RP^n\to RP^n$$ for any $n$, namely $id$ and $\sigma.$ It remains to check whether the induced two self-maps $RP^n\to RP^n$ are homotopic to each other. When $n$ is odd, they cannot be homotopic to each other since $RP^n$ is orientable, and $\sigma$ reverses orientation (so $\sigma$ can be distinguished from $id$ by looking at action on $H^n$). But when $n$ is even, the map $\sigma$ is homotopy equivalent via sphere rotations to the map $(x_1,x_2\dots, x_n)\mapsto (-x_1,-x_2\dots, -x_n),$ and this induces a homotopy between $\sigma$ and $id$ as maps $RP^n\to RP^n.$ Thus we have $$\pi_0(\mathrm{Aut}(RP^n)) \cong \begin{cases} 
\{id\}, & n \text{ even}\\
\{id, \sigma\}, & n \text{ odd}.
\end{cases}
$$
As mentioned, $RP^n$-bundles on $S^1$ are classified by the same data, so your guess is correct.

Comment: You are apparently classifying up to fibre homotopy equivalence.  As Tom Goodwillie points out, the classification up to diffeomorphism is different.

Comment: Right. Tom Goodwillie's answer came while I was writing mine, and I added a disclaimer.

Comment: And the MSE question had "diffeomorphism" in the title.

Comment: A reference for the above computation of $\pi_0(Aut(RP^n))$ can be found in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407388/do-all-spaces-doubly-covered-by-s2n-have-the-homeomorphism-type-of-mathbb/407390#407390.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Hmm, I couldn't find it there. Is it in one of the linked papers?

Comment: As I say it is Corollary 6 in "Coverings of fibrations" by Becker and Gottlieb.

Comment: OK, just confirming that your answer here is essentially an exact answer to the second part of my question from the original MSE post: "Is every diffeomorphism of even dimensional real projective space homotopic to the identity and every diffeomorphism of odd dimensional projective space is homotopic to either the identity or to an orientation reversing isometry?" And that furthermore this answer is equivalent to classifying bundles up to homotopy.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira That is correct. Here it's important that by "homotopic" we mean as a map, not as a diffeomorphism (i.e., the intermediate maps are allowed to not be invertible). Note that once you have a homotopy, you can always perturb it to be smooth.

Comment: Three different questions are possible: classification of smooth fiber bundles up to fiber-preserving diffeomorphism, classification of topological fiber bundles up to fiber-preserving homeomorphism, classification of fibrations up to fiber homotopy equivalence. I addressed the first, Vaintrob addressed the third.

Comment: Well, then there are the mixtures such as classifying smooth bundles up to fiber homotopy equivalence. Maybe that really is what you meant.

Answer (score 8):

No. Every smooth bundle over $S^1$ with fiber $M$ is the mapping torus of some diffeomorphism $f:M\to M$. Isomorphism classes of bundles correspond to conjugacy classes in the group of isotopy classes of diffeomorphisms.

There are already surprises when $M$ is $S^n$. For example, an exotic $7$-sphere can be realized as the union of two copies of $D^7$ glued by a diffeomorphism of $S^6$ that is not isotopic to the identity, and this leads to examples.

There are related examples with $M=P^n$.

Comment: For r=11mod16 the quotient of $\pi_0 Diff^+(RP^r)$ modulo concordance has been computed in Wells:The concordance group of real projective space, https://www.jstor.org/stable/1996838?seq=19#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: Or at least it has been proven to equal something else.

Comment: I am a little uneducated about exotic smooth structures. Although I am interested in both perspectives, I think the answer by Dmitry Vaintrob about classification up to homeomorphism is more what I am looking for, so I have accepted it. You are right that the MSE question had diffeomorphism in the title. Sorry if that caused any confusion. And thanks for the answer, maybe this will motivate me to look into exotic smooth structures more!

Comment: I am a little confused because Michael Albanese says " there are only two $S^n$-bundles over $S^1$ up to diffeomorphism" in his comment on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348711/mapping-torus-of-orientation-reversing-isometry-of-the-sphere?noredirect=1#comment9075822_4348711 is that consistent with what you are saying here?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira: perhaps your confusion comes from ignoring the structure group. One can classify up to fiber homotopy equivalence (as in Vaintrob's answer), fiber preserving homeomorphism, fiber preserving diffeomorphism (as in Goodwillie's answer), and also one can look at linear $S^n$ bundles over the circle, which have the structure group $O(n+1)$. Since $\pi_1(BO(n+1))\cong \pi_0(O(n+1))\cong\mathbb Z_2$ there are two linear $S^n$ bundles over $S^1$.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Just to be clear, the result I wrote only works for Serre fibrations, which are not just the "up to homeomorphism" but also the "up to homotopy" version of bundles (I edited my preamble to make that clearer). I'm not sure whether the "up to homeomorphism" result is true, perhaps someone else can comment on this.

Comment: Oh goodness! Perhaps the moral of the story here is that topology is not my area and when I talk about it I should be wary of the different notions of equivalence. While I have the attention of you fine gentleman, could I ask your opinion on whether the question "How can I see that $ \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3 $ is diffeomoprhic to a circle bundle over $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $" is appropriate for MO or if you think I should post it to MSE first?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira: yes, there is a non-orientable circle bundle over $RP^2$ whose total space is diffeomorphic to $RP^3\# RP^3$. See e.g. p.459 in Scott's "The geometries of 3-manifolds", http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2021_3MFDS/References/1983the_geometries_of_three-manifolds.pdf. It is probably not hard to describe the bundle explicitly.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  The bundle structure is quite explicit.  Deleting a ball from $\mathbb{R}P^3$, the resulting space is the total space of the disk bundle in the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^2$.  Taking two copies and gluing, we get a map $\mathbb{R}P^3\sharp \mathbb{R}P^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ with fiber obtained by gluing the two fiber $[0,1]$s to themselves along the boundary, i.e., with fiber $S^1$.  (Technically, to make everything glue up nicely, we must use $\mathbb{R}P^3\sharp -\mathbb{R}P^3$, but this is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^3\sharp \mathbb{R}P^3$.)